# While the inner method async does the outer method has to be async?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have an `async` method. Can I call it from an non-async method? Like the following

My method

```
void method() async{

await 'something'

}
```

Case 1

```
onPressed:() {
method();
}
```

Case 2

```
onPressed:() async{
await method();
}
```

Which of the above is correct? It seems to me two of them is OK. However, the second one I think works much more slower, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the caller of an `async` function must also be asynchronous if it wants to wait for the call to complete.  This makes asynchronous-ness contagious.

In your case, your `async` function is a "fire-and-forget" function; callers cannot wait for it to complete, so it doesn't matter.  Your second case (with `await method()`) is wrong because you should use `await` only on `Future`/`FutureOr`, but `method` returns `void`, so there nothing to wait for. (The Dart analyzer would warn you about this if you have the [await_only_futures lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/await_only_futures.html) enabled.)

You also could simplify your code further by using a *tear-off* instead of creating an unnecessary closure:

```dart
onPressed: method
```